# Are global variables constantly updated

Tags: c++

I know global variables are bad, however I have a checksettings function which is run every tick. http://pastebin.com/54yp4vuW The paste bin contains some of the check setting function. Before I added the GetPrivateProfileIntA everything worked fine. Now when I run it, it lags like hell. I can only assume this is because it is constantly loading the files. So my question is, are global variables constantly updated. (ie if I put this in global var will it stop the lag) 
Thanks :)

Comment: Off topic: Rather than a horde of globals, consider a structure. That way if you later find yourself needing multiple instances, you can modify the program to have and use multiple instances of the structure with a lot more ease.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Assuming I'm interpreting your question correctly, then no, global variables are not constantly updated unless you explicitly do so in code. So yes, putting those calls in global variables will get rid of the lag.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't provided any details about the design but globals are visible across the entire application and get updated when they are written into.
Multiple processes/threads reading that global variable would then read the same updated value.
But synchronizing reads/writes requires the use of synchronization mechanisms such as mutexes, condition variables etc etc.

In your case you need to decide when to call `GetPrivateProfileIntA()` for all those settings.
Are all those settings constantly updated or only a fraction of those? Identify the ones which need to be monitored periodically and only load those.

And if a setting is stateful meaning all objects of the class refer to a single copy of the setting then I would use static class variables instead of plain global variables.

Alternately you could make a JIT call to `GetPrivateProfileIntA()` where needed and not bother about storing the setting in a global variable.

Comment: A cowardly downvote without a comment proves time and again that SO needs to give the downvote privilege only to those who have a solid technical backbone